# insert xml data in mysql table

Tags: mysql, xml

I have this type of XML.

```
<Players>
      <TeamA name="Kings XI Punjab" Id="1107">
        <Player1 Id="270">Virender Sehwag </Player1>
        <Player2 Id="10114">Mandeep Singh </Player2>
        <Player3 Id="10085">Glenn Maxwell </Player3>
        <Player4 Id="5313">David Miller </Player4>
        <Player5 Id="4961">George Bailey (C) </Player5>
        <Player6 Id="4508">Wriddhiman Saha (W)</Player6>
        <Player7 Id="62576">Akshar Patel </Player7>
        <Player8 Id="3736">Mitchell Johnson </Player8>
        <Player9 Id="4610">Rishi Dhawan </Player9>
        <Player10 Id="4997">Parvinder Awana </Player10>
        <Player11 Id="10116">Sandeep Sharma </Player11>
      </TeamA>
      <TeamB name="Kolkata Knight Riders" Id="1106">
        <Player1 Id="3723">Robin Uthappa (W)</Player1>
        <Player2 Id="3478">Gautam Gambhir (C) </Player2>
        <Player3 Id="4276">Manish Pandey </Player3>
        <Player4 Id="141">Jacques Kallis </Player4>
        <Player5 Id="11803">Suryakumar Yadav </Player5>
        <Player6 Id="3724">Yusuf Pathan </Player6>
        <Player7 Id="3766">Ryan ten Doeschate </Player7>
        <Player8 Id="3729">Piyush Chawla </Player8>
        <Player9 Id="11229">Sunil Narine </Player9>
        <Player10 Id="3874">Morne Morkel </Player10>
        <Player11 Id="5221">Umesh Yadav </Player11>
      </TeamB>
    </Players>
```

i want this type opf insertion into mysql database

```
Team                     Player             TeamId        PlayerId 
Kings XI Punjab         Virender Sehwag      1107         270
Kolkata Knight Riders   Robin Uthappa        1106         3723
```

an so on..every entry for player and team and both ids should be in this format.
How can i do this.

```
TeamA            Id     Player1          Player2            Player3                               Kings XI Punjab   5313 Virender Sehwag  Mandeep Singh       Glenn Maxwell
```

I am getting this type of entry into my db. How do i get player id and name of all layers in a row instead of column

I am unable to do this by

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/pathtofile/file.xml' INTO TABLE my_tablename ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<tagname>';
```

Please give me a proper solution
thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you "unable do to this" with `LOAD XML`? Or did you mean "It does not work with..."? (in which case, please share with us what happens when it fails)

Comment: `TeamA            Id     Player1          Player2            Player3        
Kings XI Punjab  5313     Virender Sehwag   Mandeep Singh      Glenn Maxwell`

I am getting this type of entry into my db. How do i get player id and name of all layers in a row instead of column.

Comment: Please insert this important piece of information into the body of your question. Not everyone is willing to browse the comments for info. Also, you most probably want to fiddle with the [`ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<tagname>'`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-xml.html) option.